# PropertyAccess: Is there a way to create access functions dynamically?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs

Here is the thing.. I want to draw some lines into some charts for a website.
These charts sometimes will have sometimes one or two lines.. but sometimes a few more where each is defined by an arbitrary mathematical function.

As for now, I only know this possibility to draw e.g. three lines:

```
public class ArbitraryFunctionData {

  private double x1;
  private double x2;
  private double x3;
  private double y;

  public ArbitraryFunctionData(double x1, doouble x2, double x3, double y) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.x3 = x3;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public double getX1() {
    return x1;
  }

  public double getX2() {
    return x2;
  }

  public double getX3() {
    return x3;
  }

  public double getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void setX1(double x1) {
    this.x1 = x1;
  }

  public void setX2(double x2) {
    this.x2 = x2;
  }

  public void setX3(double x3) {
    this.x3 = x3;
  }

  public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Somewhere there is a need to define this interface:

```
  public interface ArbitraryFunctionAccess extends
      PropertyAccess<ArbitraryFunctionData> {

    ValueProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData, Double> x1();
    ValueProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData, Double> x2();
    ValueProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData, Double> x3();

    @Path("x")
    ModelKeyProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData> xKey();
  }
```

So I can add these access function as fields to the chart:

```
horizontalAxis.addField(arbFuncAccess.x1());
horizontalAxis.addField(arbFuncAccess.x2());
horizontalAxis.addField(arbFuncAccess.x3());
```

---

This is a very uncomfortable way to create a chart. Is there any better way to do this?
`ArbitraryFunctionData` needs to be pre defined and one needs to add every single access method by hand. I'd rather do something like that:

```
ArbitraryFunction f1 = new ArbitraryFunction(0, 5, 0, 5) {

  @Override
  public double f(double x) {
    return x+1;
  }

};

ArbitraryFunction f2 = new ArbitraryFunction(0, 5, 0, 5) {

  @Override
  public double f(double x) {
    return x+2;
  }

};

store.add(0, f1.getData()); // a line
store.add(1, f2.getData()); // another line
```

where ArbitraryFunctions function `public double f(double x)` needs to be overwritten and `ArbitraryFunction.getData()` is defined as `public List<ArbitraryFunctionData> getData()`. This would add more dynamic to the whole thing but the problem is, that I can not add the fields to the chart since they need to be pre-defined in `public interface ArbitraryFunctionAccess`.

I hope I described my need properly. Does anyone know a possible solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertyAccess` isn't the point here - `ValueProvider` is. The `PropertyAccess` type is just a nice way to auto-generate a bunch of really boring `ValueProvider`/`ModelKeyProvider`/`LabelProvider` types that you could easily do by hand. Your time is valuable, so we don't make you do it by hand.

This means that you can make a hand-made implementation of `ValueProvider` that does whatever you want it to. I'm not really clear what `0,5,0,5` means or what f1.getData() is intended to return/do, but you could define f1 as a ValueProvider type that can find objects in that list.

```
public class AribtraryDataVP implements 
        ValueProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData, Double>() {
  private final int index;
  public AribtraryDataVP(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }
  public Double getValue(ArbitraryFunctionData object) {
    return object.getData().get(index);
  }
  public void setValue(ArbtraryFunctionData object, Double value) {
    object.getData().set(index, object);
  }
  public String getPath() {
    return "data[" + index + "]";
  }
}
```

The purpose of the `ValueProvider` type is to allow access to reading and writing properties of objects. In your case, you probably don't care about `setValue`, but it is usually good to either implement it or at least throw an exception so you know that someone tried to call it and it didn't work. Likewise, the `getPath` method is used to tell the difference between properties, sometimes for debugging purposes, and sometimes for sorting or filtering on the server, which needs the name of the property it is supposed to sort/filter. Again, probably not needed in your case, but it is usually good to get right.

I think this then will do what you were trying to do, adding those ValueProviders (i.e. properties, now mapped to list items) to the chart.

```
//f1, f2
axis.addField(new AribtraryDataVP(1));
axis.addField(new AribtraryDataVP(2));
```

Comment: I took a look at it and this seems to lead me to the right direction, but it seems like I can't really work around that `@Path("x")
    ModelKeyProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData> xKey();` thing.. ArbitraryFunction is now defined as `public abstract class ArbitraryFunction implements ValueProvider<ArbitraryFunctionData, Double>` but now I don't know how to manage the ModelKeyProvider. All I want is to add mulitple lines to a chart dynamically..

Comment: You need to rephrase your question - instead of what can't be done, start with what you want to achieve, then move on to what you have tried. But to reiterate, PropertyAccess can't do anything for dynamic property sets. Drop the ArbitraryFunction idea - ValueProvider *is* that function already. And you might check out the ValueProvider section of this blog post: http://www.sencha.com/blog/building-gxt-charts/

Comment: How does a chart distinguish between lines? I know that question sounds stupid but.. I simply don't get the intention of this all and why it seems so tricky to just add a few lines to a chart..

Comment: Okay, this worked for me. Thank you for your help! May I add another question on the fly: How can I display decimal values on an e.g. vertical axis?

Comment: Use `axis.setLabelProvider(myLabelProvider)`. The default for `NumericAxis` (`RoundNumberProvider`) rounds to the nearest whole number.

Comment: Well.. may I ask you one more question.. how to set up the axis with this approach? No matter how I try, the axes aren't doing what they're supposed to do

Comment: I suggest you post at sencha.com/forum for rapid q/a like this, or sign into freenode (##gwt or #extgwt), or make new individual questions - the comment part of SO isn't meant to be used like this.